# Unsplit Up/Down Votes after Splitting them

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, downvotes, voting, upvotes

Is there a way to unsplit the up/down vote counts after splitting it.

Before splitting:

[image: Before splitting]

after Splitting:

[image: after Splitting:]

Only way i found now is refreshing the page. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: This isn't a big deal most of the time, but on questions with large vote counts, could be convenient. The breakdown is interesting (a more detailed breakdown would be more interesting), but I'd like to go back to the total and reaching ctrl to refresh is such a stretch for my little finger.

Comment: There is no practical use for this outside of the election page. You can use a custom script to only show the nameplaces and votes, and then order them by vote. `$($('table:first > tbody > tr').detach().sort(function(a, b) { return ($(b).find('.vote-count-post').text() | 0) - ($(a).find('.vote-count-post').text() | 0) })).appendTo('table:first').find('.post-text').hide();` However, even if you use this you still need to refresh the page for a current vote count as it tends to change over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote some js which does it:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('vote-count-separator');
for (var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
    parent = els[i].parentNode;
    var count = (parent.children[0].innerText.replace('+','')) 
                 - (parent.children[2].innerText.replace('-',''));
parent.innerHTML = count;
}
```

If you put `javascript:` then paste the code in your url bar, it'll replace the separated counts with the aggregated.

You could put it into a bookmark (which wouldn't really be easier than refreshing), or you might be able to use a browser extension to make it easier, but I don't know what you would use.

You know, then it screws other things up because the `onclick`s are then broken. It could be better, but it's something.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can refresh the page.

Other than that there is no mechanism to "unsplit", nor do we see a reason to add such a mechanism.

Comment: Well, not technically a mechanism to unsplit, but when anybody (oneself or others) votes on the post it automatically collapses. This of course cannot be used for any post where one's vote is already locked in.

Comment: That mechanism would be useful in Community Moderator Elections. When too many up/down votes are cast.

Comment: Too many? What do you mean by that, @ASP? And why would it be useful? What problem would that solve?

Comment: For example , After splitting the vote count of a candidate, if i want to see the total votes again, i will have to refresh the page. And after refreshing, the position of the candidate changes (as i observed in the Primary Election Page of Community Moderator Election). It would be a small help if we could unsplit the votes on clicking it again.

Comment: @ASP: There is always this old-fashioned method to the rescue whereby you take the green number and subtract the red one from it.

Comment: @AndriyM Yeah its there...but some guys might find it hard especially if the numbers are too big..

Comment: @ASP: Agreed, it's more challenging when the numbers are big, although I don't think they are too big in this case – YMMV. Either way, as l4mpi has said, the numbers automatically collapse and you see the new combined result when there's a vote, and if there's no vote since you expanded the total last, it's the same number you saw before expanding it. Whether mental arithmetic or memory exercises, it's all good for our grey matter now and then. But hey, isn't your question an XY problem actually? Because what you actually want seems to be the option of showing the candidates in a fixed order.

Comment: Yes , u are right.

Comment: hmm, my own question asks about the same subject and more a few subtle things: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338437/383779

Comment: @sergiol - sorry, I don't see anything there that changes this decision.